# Animate svg elements with Javascript and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-svg

I'm trying to animate the following `html` elements to implement a functionality similar to a volume wheel.

```html
<svg id="circle_svg" width="200" height="175">
<circle cx="100" cy="85" r="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="lightgray"/>
<line id="line_alpha" x1="100" y1="85" x2="100" y2="160" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:2"/>
<circle id="dot_alpha" cx="100" cy="160" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

The basic idea is that clicking on the red dot and moving the mouse around should result in the following behavior:

1. The red dot moves along the circle (even if mouse doesn't stay exactly on it).
2. The end point of the line on the circle follows the red dot.
3. A number shown somewhere else in the page gets incremented or decremented with the amount of angular displacement.

I found a [demo](http://www.codedread.com/dragtest.svg) online that allows to drag an svg circle all around the page, by binding the elements of interest to `mousedown` and `mouseup` events and rewriting the attribute `cx` and `cy` of the circle to the current location of the mouse.

However when testing the code on `jsfiddle` with my example (or even with the original code) something is not working. Could you please take a look and give me advice on what might be going wrong?

- [Jsfiddle my settings](https://jsfiddle.net/db1qsd2w/)
- [Jsfiddle original settings](https://jsfiddle.net/zsjktxq7/)

Comment: @Dominik - Thanks for the suggestion, but for reasons I didn't post in the question I can't simply rotate the svg tag. It has to follow the principles explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution to my question (thanks to a friend) and will post it as reference for others:

The main problem with pasting the code from this [**online demo**](http://www.codedread.com/dragtest.svg) into `jsfiddle` is that the order in which `JavaScript` libraries and functions is not predictable.

So some binding might be called before the binded function is defined.
Also, the code from the demo is more complicated that what I needed.

- Here is the code solution on [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/0hfb9595/)
- Below is a working snippet for SO site

```js
var dragging = false

var updateGraphics = function (e) {
 if (dragging) {
  
    var parentOffset = $('#wheel').offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  
    var cx = +$('#circle').attr('cx')
    var cy = +$('#circle').attr('cy')
    var r = +$('#circle').attr('r')
    var dx = relX - cx
    var dy = relY - cy
    //var dx = e.clientX - cx
    //var dy = e.clientY - cy
 
    console.debug('cx: ' + cx);
    console.debug('cy: ' + cy);
    console.debug('dx: ' + dx);
    console.debug('dy: ' + dy);

    console.debug('clientX: ' + e.clientX);
    console.debug('clientY: ' + e.clientY);
  
    console.debug('relX: ' + relX);
    console.debug('relY: ' + relY);
  
    var a = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
    var dotX = cx + r * Math.cos(a)
    var dotY = cy + r * Math.sin(a)
    $('#dot').attr('cx', dotX);
    $('#dot').attr('cy', dotY);
    $('#line_2').attr('x2', dotX);
    $('#line_2').attr('y2', dotY);
  }
}

$('svg').on('mousedown', function (e) {
 dragging = true
 updateGraphics(e)
})

$('svg').on('mouseup', function (e) {
 dragging = false
})

$('svg').on('mousemove', updateGraphics)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="wheel" width="200" height="175" style="background-color:lightgreen;">
<circle id="circle" cx="100" cy="85" r="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="lightgray"/>
<line id="line_1" x1="100" y1="85" x2="100" y2="160" stroke-dasharray="15,15" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2"/>
<line id="line_2" x1="100" y1="85" x2="100" y2="160" style="stroke:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:2"/>
<circle id="dot" cx="100" cy="160" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```